# We need to clean out our [cleaner]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleaner) has 2 questions and no usage guidance. The first one is about making cleaner CSS, whereas the other is about the `Cleaner` class in `java`.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The [cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleaner) tag does not describe the contents (only what the question seeks) to the question it is applied to. It is ambiguous because it could mean making code cleaner (which is ambiguous) or the `java` `Cleaner` class, etc.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

For making code cleaner, no. Java Cleaner classes, yes. Maybe there should be some [java-cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-cleaner) tag instead.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Nope, none.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, some are about making code cleaner, and others are about java classes.

Can we burn it?